# How can I Modify pytorch dataset __getitem__ function to return a bag of 10 images?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I have a directory with multiple images separated into folders. Each folder has up to 3000 images. I would like to modify the pytorch dataset **getitem** function so that it returns bags of images, where each bag contains 10 images.

Here is what I have so far:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                            transforms.ToTensor()
                           ])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('./../BCNB/patches/WSI_1', transform=transform)
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = 1)
```

My output of DataLoader should be a tensor with a shape of [1, 10, 3, 256, 256].
Any input would be very helpful!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need "bags of 10 images"? If you need them as *mini batches* for training -- don't change the `Dataset`, but use a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) for that. A `DataLoader` takes a dataset and does the "batching" for you.

Alternatively, you can overload the `__getitem__` method and implement your own that returns 10 images instead of just one.